# Third point of a triangle in the complex plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have an equilateral triangle with two points equal to $(2+2i)$ and $(5+i)$. I want to find the third point(s) (there are $2$ of these). I have that the side length of the triangle is $\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: Duplicate question with "Complex numbers and geometry"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A different Hint:**  if $A,B\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\omega=e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$, the points you are looking for are given by:
$$ A+(B-A)\omega, \qquad A+(B-A)\omega^{-1}.$$
This happens because the multiplication by $\omega$ ($\omega^{-1}$) acts like a $60^\circ$ ($-60^\circ$) rotation.

Comment: What do A and B represent?

Comment: The two given points, in this case $A=2+2i$ and $B=5+i$.

Comment: So the two points are ((4 +- sqrt(3))/2) + (i(4 +- 3sqrt(3))/2)?

Comment: I got $$\frac{7\pm\sqrt{3}}{2}+i\frac{3\pm 3\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$

Comment: multiplying them i got 16 + 6i

Comment: Why the product of the two solutions should be relevant?

Comment: Oh I didn't post this but the problem was actually asking for the product of the two points

Comment: Oh, ok then, the product of the two solutions is $16+6i$, yes.

Comment: Notice that since $\omega+\omega^{-1}=\omega \omega^{-1}=1$, the product of the two solutions is always $$A^2+(B-A)^2+A(B-A) = A^2-AB+B^2,$$ hence if you need to find just the product of the two solutions, you does not need to find them in a explicit form.

Comment: Oh yea thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You already  know that $\big|z-(5+i)\big|=\big|z-(2+2i)\big|=\ldots$ (you are to fulfil the gap), where $z=x+yi$ the complex number(s) you are looking for. Plus, you have an equilateral triangle, which means *all sides are equal*!

Answer (score 0):

**Yet another hint:** Why not work in $\Bbb R^2$ with vectors? You have the points $A = (2,2)$ and $B = (5,1)$, and the length $\ell = \sqrt{10}$. Find the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AB}$ and go $h = \frac{\ell\sqrt{3}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{30}}{2}$ in both senses.

Comment: I don't really know vectors

Answer (score 0):

(I'm purposely not trying 
to be clever here
and doing all calculations in my head.)

The distance
$d$
between the two known points
satisfies
$d^2
=(2-5)^2+(2-1)^2
=10
$.

If the point is
$(x, y)$,
then
$(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2
=(x-5)^2+(y-1)^2
=10
$,
or
$x^2-4x+4+y^2-4y+4
=x^2-10x+25+y^2-2y+1
=10
$,
or
$x^2-4x+y^2-4y+8
=x^2-10x+y^2-2y+26
=10
$.

Subtracting the first two,
$6x-2y-18 = 0$,
or
$y = 3x-9$.

Substituting this
in the first equation,
$10
=x^2-4x+(3x-9)^2-4(3x-9)+8
=x^2-4x+9x^2-54x+81-12x+36+8
=10x^2-70x+125
$
or
$10x^2-70x+115=0$
or
$2x^2-14x+23=0$

Using the good old
quadratic equation formuls,
$D^2 
= b^2-4ac
= 14^2-4\cdot 2 \cdot 23
=196-184
=12
$
so
$D = 2\sqrt{3}$.

The roots are therefore
$x
=\dfrac{-b \pm D}{2 a }
=\dfrac{14\pm 2\sqrt{3}}{2\cdot 2}
=\dfrac{7\pm \sqrt{3}}{2}
$
and
$y
=3x-9
=\dfrac{21\pm 3\sqrt{3}-18}{2}
=\dfrac{3\pm 3\sqrt{3}}{2}
$.

Note:
I find it somewhat 
embarrassing and dishearting
how many errors
I made
while doing this
all in my head.